# RegEx for Including special character and characters inside a [ ]

Tags: regex

I have requirement to allow Special Characters and certain other characters for a field. I am using this regular expression:

```
"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._\\-]*[@][a-zA-Z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]"
```

**So I need to add [at] instead of @ also add [.] insteat of . in my email validation**

I try Like this

```
"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._\\-]*[\\[at]\\][a-zA-Z0-9.\\-]+[\\[dot]\\][a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]"
```

But its Not Working and no idea to fix it.

Comment: Check if this will help you for email validation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: This will really helpfull for me **UOY KNAHT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._\\-]*\[at\][a-zA-Z0-9.\\-]+\[dot\][a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]"
```

Comment: Would you please explain me the use of single \ backward slash in **RegEx**..?

Comment: Square brackets are used to define character class (matching one character in the set), if you want to use the square bracket character in the regex, you have to use a backslash before that. This is true for every special character.

Comment: For example while `a*` matching with 0 or more "a" characters, the `a\*` pattern matching on literally "a*".